# Custom image as plot marker

Tags: plotting, image, textures

Is there a quick and easy way with `Graphics` to replace the standard data points in a plot with a custom image?

Answer (score 14):

There is a `PlotMarkers` option in `ListPlot`:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
ListPlot[Table[{Sin[n], Sin[2 n]}, {n, 50}], PlotMarkers -> Show[img, ImageSize -> 20]]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @Kuba Hmm, good question.

Comment: `Table[{{t, 4/5 (Sqrt[1 - t^2] + Sqrt[Abs[t]])}, {t, 
   4/5 (-Sqrt[1 - t^2] + Sqrt[Abs[t]])}}, {t, -1, 1, .2}]` :p

Comment: Awwww so cute @Kuba :D [Better with Elaine!](http://i.imgur.com/SxLIsRb.png)